# Could not deduce (a ~ [a])

Tags: list, haskell, reverse, signature, type-deduction

I try to write a function, which takes a list of sublists, reverses sublists and returns concatenated, reversed sublists. Here is my attempt:

```
conrev :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [a]
conrev [[]] = []
conrev [[a]] = reverse [a]
conrev [(x:xs)] = reverse x ++ conrev [xs]

main = putStrLn (show (conrev [[1,2],[],[3,4]]))
```

I get this error:

```
3.hs:4:27:
    Could not deduce (a ~ [a])
    from the context (Ord a)
      bound by the type signature for conrev :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [a]
      at 3.hs:1:11-31
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for conrev :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [a] at 3.hs:1:11
    In the first argument of `reverse', namely `x'
    In the first argument of `(++)', namely `reverse x'
    In the expression: reverse x ++ conrev [xs]
```

What am I doing wrong? The second question is - could the type signature be more generic? I have to write as generic as possible.

Comment: You don't need the Ord a => as far as I can see

Comment: This way: `conrev :: [[]] -> []`? I get an error, `Expecting one more argument to '[]'`

Comment: try conrev :: [[a]] -> [a]

Comment: `Couldn't match expected type 'a' with actual type '[a]'
      'a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for conrev :: [[a]] -> [a] at 3.hs:1:11`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the equation

```
conrev [(x:xs)] = reverse x ++ conrev [xs]
```

you match a list containing a single element, which is a nonempty list `x:xs`. So, given the type

```
conrev :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [a]
```

the list `x:xs` must have type `[a]`, and thus `x :: a`.

Now, you call `reverse x`, which means `x` must be a list, `x :: [b]`. And then you concatenate

```
reverse x :: [b]
```

with

```
conrev [xs] :: [a]
```

from which it follows that `b` must be the same type as `a`. But it was determined earlier that `a ~ [b]`. So altogether, the equation demands `a ~ [a]`.

If you had not written the (unnecessary) `Ord a` constraint, you would have gotten the less opaque

```
Couldn't construct infinite type a = [a]
```

error.

Your implementation would work if you removed some outer `[]`:

```
conrev :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [a]
conrev [] = []
conrev [a] = reverse a
conrev (x:xs) = reverse x ++ conrev xs
```

but the better implementation would be

```
conrev = concat . map reverse
```

Answer (score 3):

Your second pattern doesn't match what you want, it looks like you're mistaking the structure of the type for the structure of the value.

`[[a]]` as a type means "A list of lists of some type `a`"

`[[a]]` as a pattern means "Match a List containing a *single* list which contains a *single* element which will be *bound to the name* `a`.

Edit:
If I understand what you're trying to do the middle case is actually redundant.  The third case will handle non-empty lists and the first case will handle empty lists.  Making another case for the singleton list is unnecessary.

Edit 2:

There is a further problem with the implementation of the third case.

```
conrev :: Ord a => [[a]] -> [a]
conrev [(x:xs)] = reverse x ++ conrev [xs]
```

Given the type you see that `x` must be of type `[a]` and `xs` must be of type `[[a]]`.  So writing `conrev [xs]` is passing a value of type `[[[a]]]` to `conrev`.  This is where your type error is coming from.  You're implicitly stating that `[a]` is the same type as `a` by calling `convrev [xs]`.

Comment: That's exactly what I had on my mind. I have a list of sublists with some type inside (in this case I push integers). And in a pattern match, I want to handle this case, when I have only one sublist.

Comment: Right but you're conflating the type syntax with pattern matching the value.  Consider what your middle case does on the list `[[1,2]]`, you get a pattern match error.  On the case `[[1]]` `a` is bound to `1` and then you do `reverse [1]` which is technically correct but not useful.

Comment: Hmm... OK, I removed it. But I still have a `Could not deduce (a ~ [a])` problem.